# How to shuffle background color automatically on clicking a button?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to shuffle the background colors on a frame when a button is clicked..for that I've used `setBackground()` method three times but the problem is.. it only displays the color specified in third `setBackground()` ignoring the preceding two `setBackground()` colors.

```
if(s.equals("Click here")) {
            this.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException ie) 
            {}
            this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {   }
            this.setBackground(Color.red);         
 }
```

Help me find out what's wrong in my code.

Comment: does it change to red straight away or after 4000 milliseconds? Try increasing the delay so you can see. Are you running this code on the event thread? if you are you're blocking the event thread, so it can't do anything until your entire `setBackground()` method returns.

Comment: By `Thread.sleep` you just freeze UI thread giving it no chance to change a color---UI refresh cycle not executed until method returns. Approach should be based on timer/scheduling operating in separate thread (e.g. TimerTask)

Answer (score 2):

You can also work with Timer :

```
if(s.equals("Click here")) {

Timer t = new Timer();
Colors colors = new Colors[3] ; 

 colors[0] = Color.yellow;
 colors[1] = Color.cyan;
 colors[2] = Color.red;
 int i = 0 ; 

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
                     this.setBackground(colors[i]);
                     i++ ;
                     if(i==3)
                     {
                         t.cancel() ; 
                     }
        }
    },
    0,      
    2000);
}
```

Comment: Well but it throws an exception called ' Exception in thread "Time-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final' at 'i++'